# INSTR means in the sql language

Tags: oracle, sas

What does "**instr**" means in this sql query

```
instr( nvl(m.ssrmeet_sun||m.ssrmeet_mon||m.ssrmeet_tue
          ||m.ssrmeet_wed_day||m.ssrmeet_sat_day,'~')
     , substr('UMTWRFS', to_char(dt.dt,'D'),1)) > 0
```

What is this query trying to do. I need to convert this to SAS. is NVL going to be COALESCE?

Comment: check this link http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-instr.html

Comment: I have no idea what variety of SQL this is, but probably "in string."

Comment: SAS has most of the C stdlib string functions implemented, sometimes under a different name. For instr(), try to lookup strstr() or index() in the SAS manual.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some documentation on `instr()` . . . http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm.   It searches for the second argument in the first argument.  Databases have other similar functions, called things like `charindex()`, `position()`, and `locate()`.

You appear to be using Oracle as the underlying database `||` for concatenation, `instr()`, and `nvl()`.

For the last two operators, you would typically use `like` with wildcards and `coalesce()`, the ANSI standard functions for these operations.